# 900 meters above Chernobyl

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between the following?

> The airplane had to stay **above** 900 meters over Chernobyl.

> The airplane had to stay 900 meters **above** Chernobyl.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why not make your answer an answer?  Also, why have people downvoted?

Comment: Not my closevote or downvote, but apparently two people thought the question lacked "detail" and/or evidence of your own attempts to find an answer elsewhere before asking here. And two people (probably the same ones, but not necessarily) downvoted the question - probably for the same reason, though I usually think it's a bit harsh to do *both* on a single question. For me as a native speaker, the two uses of ***above*** in your examples clearly refer to different things (one refers to exceeding a value, the other to being located vertically over something). But you're not a native speaker! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice OP's two alternatives would probably both be interpreted as having the same meaning, but *in principle*, version #1 says the plane was required to be at an altitude of ***no lower*** than 900m ***if and when the plane was directly over/above Chernobyl*** (it could be higher than that, or feasibly the plane might never go over Chernobyl).

But version #2 implies the plane was required to position itself 900m ***above Chernobyl***, and just keep circling the "ghost city" at that altitude for some unspecified time.